# Java Dynamic Web Project with nodejs, angular, karma, jasmine and maven

Tags: java, angularjs, node.js, maven, karma-jasmine

I have a question related to best practice folder structure for a WEB-APPLICATION (Mobile compatible as well). I know this is opinion based question. But I did not find any good solution over internet. So I thought it will worth to post it here.

Since my project is Java based backend. So I created a dynamic web project from Eclipse with maven functionalities.

So my folder structure is just as follows.

```
SampleProkject
|
|-----src
      |
      |---- main
             |----java
             |----resources
             |----webapp
      |
      |---- test
             |---java
             |---resources
```

My all Java backend related code goes to **`src/main/java`**

and All HTML, CSS and JS goes to **`src/main/webapp`**

Similarly all my test classes for java goes to **`src/test/java`**

From Java perspective everything is fine but problem comes when I try to places my angular files.

Since I am using npm to install all required js files and frameworks. I placed **`package.json`** inside my webapp. So **`node_modules`** is also being created inside my `webapp`. Which is I do not want because node_modules is just for dependency so I do not want to expose it over HTTP. So I need to place my package.json outside of webapp. But then I can not use node_modules in index.html file because it can not access files out side of webapp.

Also I do not want to place my test cases (Karma.conf.js and Jasmine test suits) to webapp. So what I did I place those to src/test/javascript.

Now the thing is I have to access all my angular code and node_modules from src/test/javascript and also from webapp/index.html file.

Please suggest a best approach. I think several Java developer who are using angular with nodejs for UI, facing same issues.

**Note**:

> Actually I am looking for a good project structure with maven, java,
>   nodejs and angular. Which also include Java and Angular unit testes as
>   well.

Comment: I know I will get downvote as well as vote for colse this question. But I am looking for a good project structure with maven, java, nodejs and angular. with Java and Angular testes as well.

Comment: Perhaps you can post questions such as "this structure I'm using is too complicated, how can I simplify this?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many maven archtypes and yeoman generators available. But if want a good base application using angular as front end and spring/java as backend, go see http://jhipster.github.io/

Comment: Thanks for the link.